# Can I use firebase to create following backend (is it possible)?

Tags: firebase, server, google-cloud-functions, backend

(Updated description)

**Frontend:** Android

**Core requirements:** I would like to write my own code and have it executed on the server. I want the whole backend to be **automated** (no admin creating tables in a database and inserting records). I still want to benefit from some basic BaaS functions like sending notifications to users, server maintenance, etc. to speed up the MVP development process.

**Description of MVP functionality - survey app for entrepreneurs:**

1. An entrepreneur adds the survey and information about it (questions, possible answers). It is sent to the server and saved. There are different variants of surveys (single choice, multi-choice, open questions, etc.), so a specific document has to be created automatically by the backend code. Analogically, the creation of a document for responses has to be handled by the backend. The same in the case of the document for the final results of the survey research.
2. The respondent receives a notification about an available survey. The mobile app retrieves information about the survey from the server and respondent completes the survey.
3. The application sends the respondent's responses to the server, the server saves the information.
4. X respondents perform points 2 and 3.
5. When the survey is completed (the number of respondents set by the entrepreneur is reached), the server processes the data, collected from all respondents and saves the results of the research (in the appropriate document).
6. The entrepreneur receives a notification about the completed research. The application downloads the results from the server.

**Additional requirements:**

- Server has to be able to serve many entrepreneurs and respondents at the same time without any problems like data corruption.
- No admin needed for creating tables or inserting records - Backend is 100% automated.

Comment: This can be done with firebase, but I don't really know how you would do number 5. You could do this with cloud functions and firebase firestore

Answer (score 0):

Certainly!

You could use your admin client side of the application to upload the questions, corresponding answers, answer response limit, and completion flag (Step 1).

You could then retrieve the data from your user side of the client app from Firebase Firestore, and have the users complete the surveys and upload the answers back to Firebase Firestore. (Steps 2 & 3).

Step 5 could be achieved by using Firebase cloud functions, which listen when a Firestore document variable has reached the response limit, it could then be marked as complete. Step 6 could also be activated in the cloud function, sending a notification via FCM to your admin client.

I know this answer doesn't go into any code specifics, just wanted to let you know that this is most certainly possible with Firebase :)

I would certainly recommend creating an admin client app in addition to the user client app, rather than placing them in the same app!

Comment: This is possible, Cloud Functions supports PubSub - Cron jobs, and database triggers